# Avoid persisting mongo data in docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker compose to run tests for my application. The configuration looks like:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: myapp:web
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2.6
```

Right now, when I run `docker-compose up`, there is a volume created automatically (by `docker-compose` or the `mongo` image?) which maps the Mongo storage data to path like: /var/lib/docker/volumes/c297a1c91728cb225a13d6dc1e37621f966067c1503511545d0110025479ea65/_data.

Since I am running tests rather than production code, I'd actually like to *avoid* this persistence (the mongo data should go away when the docker-compose exits) -- is this possible? If so, what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

After the containers exit (or you stop them with a down command), clean up the old containers and volumes with

```
  docker-compose rm -v
```

The -v tells it to also remove the volumes (container volumes and named volumes created with docker-compose, but not host volumes).